# C#, difference between System.Window.Controls and System.Windows.Forms?

Tags: c#

Don't know the difference between the `System.Window.Controls.TextBox` and `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`. Noticed that the `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` can have `InvokeRequried` but `System.Window.Controls.TextBox` cannot.

what's the counterpart of `InvokeRequired` for `System.Window.Controls.TextBox`?

looks like if we have both `using System.Window.Controls;` and `using System.Window.Forms;` the code may conflict each other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms` is WinForms and uses code to lay out controls, `System.Windows.Controls` is [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) and uses XML ([XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) specifically) to lay out controls.

The two are NOT made to work together.  Additionally, WPF only exists in .NET 3.0 and newer.

Or were you looking for more than that?

Comment: You don't NEED to use XAML for WPF layout, although many people find it convenient and powerful.  The real differences between Windows Forms and WPF have to do with the presentation model and the flexibility of WPF.

Answer (score 6):

`System.Windows.Forms` is WinForms.
`System.Windows.Controls` is WPF.

They have nothing whatsoever in common and cannot be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

And to answer your question about the WPF `InvokeRequired` equivalent, I'd suggest you look up the `Dispatcher` on MSDN.